# How Can I Use ifeq or ifdef in Makefile on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I want to make my makefile auto detect os versions and react differently for the make clean command, since -rm won't work on Windows and del won't work on Linux.

However, Windows does not seem to know what ifeq is.

```
CreateProcess(NULL, ifeq(Windows_NT,Windows_NT), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there a solution to the problem?

This is what I have right now. I tried switching ifeq to ifdef. Didn't work.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I. -lm -g
DEPS = *.h
OBJ = objPos.o objPosArrayList.o objPosDLinkedList.o Test.o  

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

Lab2: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

test:   testLab2
testLab2:
    ./run.sh

.PHONY: clean




clean:
    ifdef OS
        del *.o *.exe
    else
        $(RM) *.o *.exe
```

Comment: Where did you get Make? [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) lets you use Linux utilities on Windows from makefiles, and I'd just declare other Make distributions too fringe to support.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat From MSYS2 using mingw32-make

Comment: IIRC, GNU Make will define the variable `$(RM)` to be the correct for the host system.

Comment: Can you confirm that Linux-style `rm` doesn't work for you in a makefile? Did you try it?

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720186/939557