makefile ifeq ignores 1st choice and accepts 2nd choice
I have an abbreviated makefile script which does the following:
HOST=$(shell hostname)
STRIPPED_HOST=$(strip $(HOST))
# Debug: Print the retrieved and stripped hostname
$(info HOST is '$(HOST)')
$(info STRIPPED_HOST is '$(STRIPPED_HOST)')
...
$(info PKGS_ROOT is '$(PKGS_ROOT)')
ifeq ($(STRIPPED_HOST), "gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov")
    PLTFRM_LIBS_HDF := $(PKGS_ROOT)/hdf/linux64/hdf-4.2.13/lib/libmfhdf.a $(PKGS_ROOT)/hdf/linux64/hdf-4.2.13/lib/libdf.a
else
    PLTFRM_LIBS_HDF := $(PKGS_ROOT)/hdf-4.2.15_post0_jpl/lib/libmfhdf.a $(PKGS_ROOT)/hdf-4.2.15_post0_jpl/lib/libdf.a
endif
$(info PLTFRM_LIBS_HDF is $(PLTFRM_LIBS_HDF))

I got:
HOST is 'gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov'
STRIPPED_HOST is 'gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov'
PKGS_ROOT is '/tools/share/COTS/sdptk_hdf.el8/supplibs'
PLTFRM_LIBS_HDF is /tools/share/COTS/sdptk_hdf.el8/supplibs/hdf-4.2.15_post0_jpl/lib/libmfhdf.a /tools/share/COTS/sdptk_hdf.el8/supplibs/hdf-4.2.15_post0_jpl/lib/libdf.a
It acts as if it did not recognize
STRIPPED_HOST is 'gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov'
both PLTFRM_LIBNS_HDF are preceded by <TAB>
I've tried many things but I'm stuck.

That's because the string gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov is not the same as the string "gs6102dsc-airstestr8.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov".  The latter has quotes and the former does not so they are not the same string.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330243/gnu-makefile-how-to-and-when-to-quote-strings/23332194#23332194

FWIW, from what I can see here you do NOT want to prefix the assignments with TAB.  TAB should only ever be used to introduce a shell command, in a recipe.  It should never be used to indent normal makefile lines.  It will work, in some situations, but it is very brittle and can break easily.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712585/when-to-use-space-or-tab-in-makefile/28720186#28720186
